# how to see list in search at opencart when i click on bottom list?

Tags: opencart

I am beginner in OpenCart and customizing a theme --- i have a problem in s search.

when i was clicking on list and i see page like 
http://irbluelink.com/open/index.php?route=product/search&search=%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA

---

but i want to see like 
http://demo.towerthemes.com/tt_outline/index.php?route=product/search&search=Accumsan%20Elit

could any one help me for it, Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your problem. In both pictures, there is an icon marked with an arrow, but it is the same icon, and I cannot see which difference you are looking for

Comment: when i clicked on icon at my site ,i can't see sort product like pic2-

Comment: @hodakakhki the question is not yet clear. both the pics show the arrow marked to `list/grid'. what is the issue?

Comment: @Rohit Batra please check links.i have problem at list.

Comment: @hodakakhki I still didn't get your problem, the links you attached work fine as I see them. the `grid` button displays your search results in a `grid` format & the `list` icon shows the results as `list` format

Comment: دوست عزیز سوالتون واضح نیست.